# How to use SpringMVC without Controller using ViewControllerRegistry with addViewController() and so on?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, redirect

I am reading followoing article:

https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-without-controller-using-viewcontrollerregistry-with-addviewcontroller-addredirectviewcontroller-and-addstatuscontroller-example

There is mapping configuration provided:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("myhome");
    registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("helloworld");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/home", "/hello");
    registry.addStatusController("/detail", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);        
}
```

The author writes:

> 1. When we access URL /hello then helloworld.jsp will run.
> 2. When we access URL /home then helloworld.jsp will run because it will be redirected to the URL /hello.
> 3. When we access URL /detail then we will get header response with 400 HTTP status code.

Thus the line

```
registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("myhome");
```

is useless?

Also in other tutorial I've found following configuration:

```
 @Override
 public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
     super.addViewControllers(registry);
     registry.addViewController("/")
            .setViewName("forward:/index");
     registry.addViewController("/index");
     registry.addViewController("/securedPage");
 }


registry.addViewController("/")
                .setViewName("forward:/index");
```

This line is clear. It means if I try to access root url application retuns index.jsp

But what the meaning of the

```
registry.addViewController("/index");
registry.addViewController("/securedPage");
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the redirect will overwrite the original mapping that was

```
registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("myhome");
```

As for the view controllers without an explicit view name set, they will (try to) show `index.jsp` and `securedPage.jsp` respectively.

From `ViewControllerRegistration.setViewName(String viewName)`:

> Set the view name to return. Optional.
>
> If not specified, the view controller will return `null` as the
>   view name in which case the configured `RequestToViewNameTranslator`
>   will select the view name. The `DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator` for
>   example translates "/foo/bar" to "foo/bar".

So the `RequestToViewNameTranslator` will convert `/securedPage` to `securedPage` and a `ViewResolver` (in this case for JSP `InternalResourceViewResolver`) will then find the JSP based on that.